# Add-Migration without nuget package possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

Trying to use `Entity Framework 7 RC1`, I saw that the nuget package includes a gazillon files (actually 171 Files, 130 Folders), which I do not want to check into my source control.

I am trying to go for the minimal approach and use and checkin only stuff I use. So I was able to get the dll usage down to 3 dlls `Core, Relational and Sqlite`.

So the main EF stuff will work with these, and everything is good. But, now I want migrations, so I have to re-get that nuget package with a gazillion dlls / scripts just to run `"Add Migration"`.

So to cut it short, how do I add a migration manually, since my project is small, I am the only developer, the db changes will be all basic and controlled by me, I can handle writing it by myself, but would it work? and what is the format / structure of the migration files?

Please do not answer with "why do you not want to use nuget" or "nuget is the future" or something like that.

Comment: NuGet files are stored in a "packages" directory outside the project folder by default so that they don't have to be checked in to source control; if the packages directory isn't on the machine the first time you build, then NuGet will download the appropriate packages, so not using it for purposes of saving on source control check ins is a non-issue.

Comment: @Claies how about, I don't want it to download the nuget package on deploy or have any reference to anything on the internet.

Comment: then you can't use migrations.  The migrations process is a very complex process that examines your database, your models, creates the base code for up/down methods, manages the __migrationHIstory table, etc.  Trying to do this all by hand would be very error prone, and at that point you would be better off simply using SQL Management Studio to create the tables you want.

Comment: @Claies I would know that I have just added a column, or table, so I do not need it to check anything. The __migrationHistory table and format of the class / designer files is the only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately @Claies is incorrect. I can use migrations without Nuget. I worked it out, and its not difficult.

## Assemblies Needed

18 assemblies are required (since they all got split up into a more modular fashion after 6.1). These can be extracted from the Nuget package which is downloadable.

```
EntityFramework.Relational, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
EntityFramework.Sqlite, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
System.Interactive.Async, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Remotion.Linq, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fee00910d6e5f53b
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

## __EFMigrations Table:

No need to worry about this, as the EF assemblies take care of creating this

## Migration Scripts

Nuget "Add-Migration" command adds 3 files (migration .cs, a designer .cs & snapshot), but really I found that only one is needed for a migration.

First make a directory called "Migrations". Then place in it .cs files with this kind of structure :

```
[DbContext(typeof(BloggingContext))]
[Migration("151205_01")]
public class InitialMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) 
    {
        // create table, add columns / keys etc.
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // opposite of "Up", ie. drop table
    }

    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // can remain blank, not sure what its used for
    }
}
```

I think its good to name these files like "yyMMdd-rr" where r = revision, so that they are always sorted in order and run in order.

## How to apply migrations

Just call :

```
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    db.Database.Migrate();
}
```

EF 7 cannot do this on context instantiation but it can be done when starting up your application. If there are any pending migrations they will be run.

## That's it.